# Reducing AmChart build size

Tags: amcharts

im using AmChart V4 (Maps) with Angular and TypeScript.

Currently when im building the application for production I get a "pdfmake" file which costs about 2 MB.
Is it possible to remove the dependency because I don't need the feature to build pdfs.

And if it is possible to disable / remove the dependency, how is it done?

Is there a guide for deployment (for AmChart)?

Answer (score 1):

In webpack config write this:

```js
externals: function (context, request, callback) {
  if (/xlsx|canvg|pdfmake|moment/.test(request)) {
    return callback(null, "commonjs " + request);
  }
  callback();
}
```

Source: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/82#issuecomment-607546562